# Movie or TV film featuring 'Vapourising' Pill?

Tags: story-identification

I remember watching a Sci-Fi or Action Movie film, possibly 1960s or 70s that featured a scene were when swallowing a bizarre 'pill' the victim simply vanished or vaporised etc

One particular scene is were a female agent secretes the pill into her mouth then seduces a lab worker, kissing him and forcing the pill into his...'WHAP!' he instantly disappears

Film was similar to Our Man Flint type

Anyone know name of film please?

Thanks